# About the terminology "shrink regularly"

Tags: terminology, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I would like to ask about the term "shrink regularly"(or bounded eccentricity) in Lebesgue differentiation theorem. In Real Analysis(Measure theory, integration & Hilbert spaces) by Elias M.Stein, the term is defined as follows:

> A collection of measurable sets $\{U_\alpha\}$ is said to shrink regularly to a point p (or has bounded eccentricity at p) if there exists $c>0$ s.t for all $U_\alpha$ and a ball $B$ satisfying
> $$p \in B ,\quad U_\alpha \subset B, \quad m(U_\alpha)\geq c\cdot m(B)$$

I see no reason why the term "shrink" is in the name. The three conditions above does not give any information about $m(U_\alpha)$ shrinking. Only after as we give the limit of $m(U_\alpha) \to 0$ with $U_\alpha$ shrinking regularly to $p$, this collection of sets "shrink". Otherwise, with just the given definition above, $m(U_\alpha)$ can be increasing, decreasing, or even constant. If my understanding is correct, then wouldn't this mean that it might be impossible to take the limit of $m(U_\alpha) \to 0$, if the limit does not exist?

Also, I noticed that $p$ not need to be in $U_\alpha$. What is the point of this definition, if it "shrinks" to $p$, but doesn't contain $p$?

Comment: You are right, the set are not shrinking. For a better definition of sets shrinking to $p$ nicely see Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see that Rudin defines "shrinking nicely" by having a sequence of balls $B_i$'s such that the radius of the balls converge to $0$. That would secure that $m(U_\alpha)$ converge to $0$. However, I still don't know my answer for the second question. I get that the question is little vague, but if $p$ need not to be in $U_\alpha$, what is the point of this definition?

Comment: Single points have Lebesgue measure $0$. So $p$ belonging to $U_{\alpha}$ or not is immaterial in measure theory. There are balls  containing $p$ whose diameters tend to $0$ and $U_{\alpha}$'s are subsets of those balls.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh..I get it. Great! Thanks for the clarification.